# Remix: programatically trigger loader

Tags: remix.run

Does Remix have a direct way to programatically trigger the current route's loader?

As a workaround, I'm using the function provided by `useSubmit` to fire an 'empty' action - the action itself does nothing but *all* actions trigger the loader, so it does what I want.

I suppose this is fine but feels quite hacky. I somewhat expected there to be a built-in API for doing this, but can't find anything by googling.

Perhaps it's just that programatically triggering loaders is against the 'Remix way' - indeed the usecase I need this for involves somewhat dynamic UI which is why I can't just rely on the regular action -> reload workflow - but curious if anyone knows of a direct, or less hacky, way to do this?

Comment: It depends on what you're building and the "mutation" you're dealing with. E.g an app with a search + filters that on submit update the query string should use an action with a redirect to the location with the query strings, this should trigger the loader (as any action). You can also use `useFetcher` which doesn't add to the history stack. Or just use a regular action if you're mutating stuff on the backend and wait until the loader revalidates. Also checkout: [fetcher.load()](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#fetcherload)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate(‘.’, { replace: true })
```

This will act like you are navigating to the current `’.’` route which will call the loader for the current page. Add the replace if you want to ensure the history stack remains the same.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: This is an interesting alternative I hadn't thought of, but without any explanation I don't see how it's less hacky than my current way :-) If you can provide some I'll certainly give you an upvote!

Comment: I added more details

Comment: thanks for the extra info, but I consider this probably even more misdirection that just firing an action. At least with an action I can give it an appropriate name to make clear what its purpose is :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically call loaders in Remix you can use the [useFetcher hook](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.14.3/hooks/use-fetcher#fetcherstate) provided by Remix. The hook returns an object with a "load" function which you can use to fetch data from a loader. The data is then stored in the "data" prop from the object and can be accessed by that prop. The load function expects an url as parameter.
If the loader is located in /routes/foo/bar.tsx, then the url would be /foo/bar.